# How to create a randomized quote generator?

Tags: javascript, quotes

I'm building a positive affirmation generator and would like some input. I'm trying to figure out how to generate quotes. I already written down the Math.random. Here's some code.

```js
function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (positiveAff.length));
  document.getElementById(affirmations).innerHTML = positiveAff[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Positive Affirmations Generator</h1>

  <div id="affirmations">

  </div>
  <button onclick="newQuote()">Click to change affirmations</button>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `positiveAff`? Where is it defined?

Comment: The positiveAff is defined as a array full of quotes that I didn't include. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Please include the array in your code. Also, what issues do you face with this code?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't sure to add it. It won't generate quotes for some reason.

Comment: Please update the post with that array, so that your issue can be properly reproduced.

Comment: `affirmations` in `document.getElementById(affirmations).innerHTML` should be a string (wrapped in quotes) like `document.getElementById("affirmations").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

My answer is by assuming you will have an array of quotes.

```js
const positiveAff = [
{ id: 1, quote: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!" },
{ id: 2, quote: "consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!" },
{ id: 3, quote: "amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!" }]

const button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  newQuote()
})
function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (positiveAff.length));
  document.getElementById("affirmations").innerHTML = positiveAff[randomNumber].quote;
}
```

```html
<h1>Positive Affirmations Generator</h1>
<div id="affirmations"></div>
<button id="button">Click to change affirmations</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snippet, the problem is not your code to get the quote. The issue was how you wrote it. In `document.getElementById(affirmations)` you use `affirmations` as a variable, which is never defined. I changed it to a string, and added an array, and now it works.

```js
   positiveAff = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!",
  "consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!",
  "amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, dolores!"
]

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (positiveAff.length));
  document.getElementById('affirmations').innerHTML = positiveAff[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<h1>Positive Affirmations Generator</h1>
<div id="affirmations"></div>
<button onclick="newQuote()">Click to change affirmations</button>
```